# sale error al instalar mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django

en el entorno virtual de django he puesto pip install mysqlclient y me sale el siguiente error

```
(venv) PS F:\Aplicativos Web\Sistema_Integrado\django\Sis_integrado\bdMysql> pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      # Options for building extention module:
        library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\lib\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\lib']
        libraries: ['kernel32', 'advapi32', 'wsock32', 'shlwapi', 'Ws2_32', 'crypt32', 'secur32', 'bcrypt', 'mariadbclient']
        extra_link_args: ['/MANIFEST']
        include_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\include\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\include']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('__version__', '2.2.0')]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      running egg_info
      writing src\mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\MySQLdb\_mysql.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-to
ols/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Verifica versiones de tu python pip install mysqlclient==1.3.1
Intenta este

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 maneras para resolver tu problema:

1. Proba instalar menor version de `mysqlclient`, algo version va a trabajo con viejo `Microsoft Visual C++`. Esto es posible con:
   `pip install mysqlclient==` para mostrar un list con todos versiones
   `pip install mysqlclient==x.x.x` para instalar el version specifico.
2. Proba actualizar tu Microsoft Visual C++ y despues, repete instalar `mysqlclient`